# input method fail to work on browser/libreoffice and other applications (works on system)

Tags: nautilus, libreoffice, language-support, ibus, input-language

I have been using 14.04LTS since last year.

I uses a few different input methods for Traditional Chinese characters. One of them is the "yong" input method, and also the "quick-classic" provided by the system.

After an update this morning, the input method started to misbehave.
I can switch from one input method to the other, i.e. I can see in the "Text Entry bar" on top right corner switching it's indication from "En" to "Yo"(for yong). And the floating bar for yong also comes up as always.
However, when I start typing in libreoffice writer, standard English characters come up instead of Chinese characters.

I tried to type in firefox and chrome which both gave me same result.

However, when I type in the search field in a Nautilus browser, the input method works fine and chinese characters comes up. The same happen to when I type in console.

Can anyone show me some insight on how to trouble shoot this one?

Comment: Can you tell me what font are you using in firefox from Options -> Content -> Fonts? Maybe fonts have been updated, and your current font do not support chineese? Can you try changing the font in FF to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Have you tried to simply reboot after the update?

Comment: Hi  shaddy, thanks for getting back. Default font is serif. I tried Arial, AR PL UMing TW, Times new Roman. restarting FF each time I changed. Sadly,  no improvement....

Comment: Hi Gunnar, Yes, I have reboot the system a few times after the update. Nothing has improved. What I also found out is that while iBus is not responding in libreoffice/firefox/chromium, it works fine in the 'Text Editor' - the system default word processor. I wonder if somehow through updates or by my mistake I have accidentally disabled iBus function on software? anyone knows how to turn it back on? or thinks it's a different issue? Thanks.